# How do I defne a stream for passing between modules

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I have some code designed to send a pdf file back to a web brower.  In that code the http server hands over a response stream which I can pipe my pdf ooutput to.

```
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
 var doc = new PDFKit({size: 'A4', layout: 'landscape', info: info, margin: 30});
 doc.pipe(res);
 doc.text('Writing text to document');
 doc.end();
});
```

I now want to use nodemailer to mail the same pdf documents as attachments.  So I think I need to do something like this

```
  const Stream = require('stream').Readable; 
  const stream = new Stream();
  transport.sendMail({
  to: someone@somewhere,
  subject: 'Info You Wanted',
  text: 'The data you want is in pdf attachments',
  attachments: [{
    filename: 'dummy.pdf',
    content:stream
  }]
 });
 const doc = new PDFKit({size: 'A4', layout: 'landscape', info: info, margin: 30});
 doc.pipe(stream);
 doc.text('Writing text to document');
 doc.end();
```

This is where I am confused. Is the above correct?  The docs imply I should be extending a Readable, but I am not sure what

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you do it:

Create a class the extends `stream.PassTrough`

```
  const PassThrough = require('stream').PassThrough;
  class Tunnel extends PassThrough {
    constructor() {
      super();
    }
    setHeader() {
      //no op
    }
  }
```

Create a new instance of this class and pass it to the doc and mail attachments

```
  const tunnel = new Tunnel();
  transport.sendMail({
  to: someone@somewhere,
  subject: 'Info You Wanted',
  text: 'The data you want is in pdf attachments',
  attachments: [{
    filename: 'dummy.pdf',
    content:tunnel
  }]
 });
 const doc = new PDFKit({size: 'A4', layout: 'landscape', info: info, margin: 30});
 doc.pipe(tunnel);
 doc.text('Writing text to document');
 doc.end();
```

I had to create a slight variation to the normal PassThrough stream, because the actual pdf processing software through it was replying to an http request and so sets headers and status.

Answer (score 0):

PDFDocument instances are readable Node streams. ***They don't get saved anywhere automatically***, but you can call the pipe method to send the output of the PDF document to another writable Node stream as it is being written. When you're done with your document, call the end method to finalize it. Here is an example showing how to pipe to a file or an HTTP response.

**doc.pipe fs.createWriteStream('/path/to/file.pdf')**  # write to PDF
                                                                    **doc.pipe res**                           # HTTP response

The write and output methods found in PDFKit before version 0.5 are now deprecated

you refer this site for more informations......good luck...
*http://pdfkit.org/docs/getting_started.html*

Comment: As you can see, my question already is doing `doc.pipe(res)`; (javascript version of your coffee script), but what does that mean within the context of nodemailer attachments.  Do I put doc as the content: value in the first object in the attachments array?

Comment: hi akc...you trying to convert data into Docs string before sending it...

Comment: also search for some informations like....                                 https://www.npmjs.com/package/to-csv